# Capture return type of templated callable object with using

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is there a way to get the type of a callable template argument (lambda, callable class, function pointer) with a using at the class level

```
template <typename FunctionType>
class SomeClass {
    using FunctionReturnType = /* extract return type of FunctionType */
};
```

I've messed around with `decltype` and `result_of`, and given an instance of a `FunctionType` along with arguments I've done it inside of a member function, however it seems there should be a way to do this at the class level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were doing wrong, this seems to work for me:

```
    template <class FType>
    struct SomeClass
    {
        using FunctionReturnType = 
            decltype(std::declval<FType>()(std::declval<int>()));
    };

    int f(int){return 0;}
    SomeClass<decltype(f)>::FunctionReturnType t = 0;
```

I just remembered that I had this code that I found somewhere on this site a while ago:

```
    #include <functional>

    template<typename T> 
    struct function_traits_impl;

    template<typename R, typename ...Args> 
    struct function_traits_impl<std::function<R(Args...)> >
    {
        static const std::size_t nargs = sizeof...(Args);

        typedef R result_type;

        template <std::size_t i>
        struct arg
        {
            typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...> >::type type;
        };
    };

    template <class R, class T, class ... Args>
    function_traits_impl<std::function<R(Args...)> > function_traits(R(T::*)(Args...)const)
    {
        return function_traits_impl<std::function<R(Args...)> >();
    }

    template <class R, class T, class ... Args>
    function_traits_impl<std::function<R(Args...)> > function_traits(R(T::*)(Args...))
    {
        return function_traits_impl<std::function<R(Args...)> >();
    }

    template <class R, class ... Args>
    function_traits_impl<std::function<R(Args...)> > function_traits(R(*)(Args...))
    {
        return function_traits_impl<std::function<R(Args...)> >();
    }
```

You may find it useful.  It is used like:

```
    typedef decltype(function_traits(&f)) f_info;
    static const unsigned num_args = f_info::nargs;
    typedef f_info::arg<0>::type arg_type;
    typedef f_info::result_type result_type;
```

and it allows you to get the number of arguments, their types and a function's return type without knowing anything about the function *a priori*.  `function_traits` is overloaded for member functions as well as free functions so it will work with both.

I don't remember where I found this exactly, but it was around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/) somewhere.